# Silverlight Out of Browser application wouldn't start, while web version is working just fine

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I got a commercial app, which works for a lot of customers.

One guy however has this problem:

After he installs OOB app to his computer and then hits its icon to launch it nothing happens.
I checked myself, icon is pointing at sllauncher just like everyones else.

SL was reinstalled yesterday, its the most recent version (5.xxx).

He says everything had been working fine, but he had fought a virus recently, and after that it stopped to work. Its not 100% that this virus and anti virus check are the reason, but thats the only system change he can name, which happened recently.

What could be the problem you think?

This sllauncher is pretty annoying to debug I guess as it doesnt give any clues, simply nothing happens.

App doesn't require elevated trust.

update: I did check event viewer and there is nothing interesting

Comment: Does the app require elevated trust? If so the user might have changed his browser's security settings

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd , no it doesn't. Are there any settings however associated with SL launcher anywhere I wonder?

Comment: no its normal windows 7 pc

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable to anti-virus and run it - if it runs, Add an exception in the anti virus. 
Also, go to the file properties and check that you don't need to unblock the file.

Comment: Of-course we did try running it without anti-virus, and it doesn't run. In file properties there are no unblock options. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Two things worth trying:

First, right-click on your application icon and choose "Run as Administrator" to invoke it.

Second, if that doesn't work, consider uninstalling your application, and re-installing it.

This is achieved in Windows 7 by doing Start/Control Panel/Programs and Features.  Then in the list find the name of your Silverlight application. Right-click on it, and choose "Uninstall".
Then re-install it in the same way your other customers do their installs.

Comment: Tried both, doesn't help sadly.